# How do I make my Facebook page plugin responsive?

Tags: html, css, facebook-social-plugins

I wish to make my Embedded Facebook Plugin responsive to screen width.

The plugin I am using is from [this site](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/page-plugin/), and I have checked the box saying **Adapt to plugin container width**.

Currently my plugin is not responsive.

```css
.socialDivContainer {
  margin: 0px 0 0 0;
  text-align: center;
  max-width: 500px;
}

.socialDivContainer div {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 60px;
  margin: auto;
  max-width: 500px;
}
```

```html
<div class="socialDivContainer">

  <div class="fb-page" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/flatworlddigital/" data-tabs="timeline" data-width="500" data-small-header="false" data-adapt- container-width="true" data-hide-cover="false" data-show-facepile="true">

    <blockquote cite="https://www.facebook.com/flatworlddigital/" class="fb- 
    xfbml-parse-ignore"><a href="https://www.facebook.com/flatworlddigital/">FlatworldWorks</a>

    </blockquote>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove `data-width="500"`, as it sets the plugin to a static width. It does not make sense to use that parameter in combination with the responsive attribute. I just tried creating the code without that parameter and it works for me.

Edit: Also, set `data-adapt-container-width="true"`

Comment: That has set the width to 191px, and it still isn't responsive. When you inspect the plugin it has lots of divs inside it that have widths on them, and i cant edit those in my css document.

Comment: This won't work. Facebook page plugin states that the max width is 500. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/page-plugin/

Comment: data-adapt-container-width="true" might be what you want in addition, but you still need to remove any static width. not sure what you mean with "won't work", to be honest?